# Advice on personal portfolio landing page

Tags: website-design, copywriting, landing-page, branding, portfolio

I am a product designer and I have worked on several B2B SaaS products last six years. The problem is that these products already had a brand. So I am not an expert on branding and marketing something from scratch. This problem crept into my own professional life because I am quite clueless how I should market myself as a designer.

On portfolio landings, I have observed three trends going on currently, where a designer -

1. Plainly introduces themselves and their skills in a very no-beating-around-the-bush way.
2. Portrays them larger than life (eg. "I am a design wizard", "I am design hero" etc).
3. Uses catchy marketing phrases that blurs the line between a designer and product or agency (eg. "one stop solution for your design needs", "**we** make products reach their goal", "product delivering machine" etc.) Pardon my copyrighting skills, but you got the point.

Yes I know we designers test what is working by testing iterations. I have tried the first and the third method but I am having trouble understanding what works because since I am not a renowned designer who is always being looked up, the analytics don't really say what drew the viewer to my portfolio. Important to mention, I have not gotten any organic lead from my website. Recruiters visit it after I have applied for a job.

I was hoping I could get some advice or suggestions on how to market myself as a designer, have more organic views and have a landing page that converts.

If it matters: I feel that I should tell the viewers why they should hire me (because of my skills) in engaging way and because I recently relocated to another country, I think I should let them know where I am from.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what country you're located in right now, but I'm hearing that in the US, there are currently 700-1000 applicants per open UX position for remote work. (The odds are more favorable for experienced onsite job applicants.)

So, with that in mind, what you should probably *not* do, is the generic "Hi , I'm Bluebug, and I love designing great products!" You're probably detecting that, too.

I'm currently leading my team through a great course called [Learn UI Design](https://learnui.design) and I don't want to give away the instructor's material, as it's how he makes a living - but he advises figuring out who you (or the brand you are working on) are and who you are not by making a list of adjectives. Would you put yourself more on the friendly/informal side of the spectrum? Or the more elegant/formal side? Do you pride yourself on being educated? Or unpretentious? Hard-working workhorse? Or more of a leader who works through other people and sells big ideas?

If you don't know who you are in a professional setting, take the [DISC](https://discpersonalitytesting.com/free-disc-test/) assessment and see what resonates from the report. Knowing that you're metrics-driven, or a cross-functional team builder, or an idea influencer is an awesome way to introduce yourself in a portfolio.

Next, when you figure out your personal brand, find things that match your brand. Are you really quirky and creative? Educated and serious? What websites and apps convey that? What fonts and colors do they use? What's the language like?

Too many designers who are seeking work just want to land anything, and end up looking unopinionated and dull. Your considered design choices will help you connect with the places you're meant to work, and root out the wrong ones.

Just as an aside - you're probably not going to get organic web traffic for a while unless you are really niche with lots of specific keywords, e.g., "I am a senior UX SAAS medical platform designer located in Berlin". That's okay. You don't need organic traffic. You just need your LinkedIn profile in the right hands, and your portfolio to stand out and make hiring managers want to talk to you.

Comment: Thank you a lot. These are some great advices I can start with. Yeah having my portfolio stand out is the complicated part. I have a few ideas but not sure which one will work out.

Comment: Advice from a hiring manager - the #1 thing that will make it stand out is if you've solved a problem in the industry I work in. Make sure that's not buried too deep.